# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to make a simple shotgun game where the user vs the CPU and the both pick shot, shield or reload but in my switch statement and in my if statement when I try use UserOption it gives me the error

> Operator `==` cannot be applied to operands of type `ShotgunGame.Program.ShotgunOption` and `int` .

I am not sure as to how to fix this.

Any Guidance would be appreciated

```
//Declare Variables
        Console.Title = "Welcome To The Shotgune Game";
        int CPUBullets = 3, userBullets = 3;
        ShotgunOption UserOption;
        int computerChoice, userScore = 0;
        bool QUIT = false;
        double gameCount = 0.0;
        Random computer = new Random();

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("SHOOT RELOAD SHIELD");

        UserOption = GetOptionFromUser();
        ShotgunOption CPUOption = (ShotgunOption)computer.Next(1, 3); // 1 is Shot, 2 is Reload, 3 is Shield

         do
        {


            if (UserOption == "QUIT")
            {
                break;
            }

            do
            {
            //Console.Write("Please enter choice, or enter QUIT to quit: ");




              switch (UserOption)
            {
                case "SHOOT":
                    if (CPUOption == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Shoot. It was a tie!", userChoice);
                        ; userBullets --;CPUBullets --; ++gameCount;
                    }
                    else if (CPUOption == 2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Reload. You win!", userChoice);
                        ++userScore; ++gameCount;
                    }
                    else if (CPUOption == 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Shield. No Damage!", userChoice);
                        ++gameCount;
                    }
                    break;
                case "RELAOD":
                    if (CPUOption == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Shoot. You lose!", userChoice);
                         ++userScore; ++gameCount;
                    }
                    else if (CPUOption == 2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Reload. You Both Gain A bullet", userChoice);
                        userBullets++; CPUBullets++; ++gameCount;
                    }
                    else if (CPUOption == 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Shield. No Damage!", userChoice);

                    }
                    break;
                case "SHIELD":
                    if (CPUOption == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Shoot. You lose!", userChoice);
                        ++gameCount;
                    }
                    else if (CPUOption == 2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Reload. You win!", userChoice);
                        ++userScore; ++gameCount;
                    }
                    else if (CPUOption == 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Shield. No Damage!", userChoice);
                        ++gameCount;
                    }
                    break;                  

            }
          }
            while (UserOption != ShotgunOption.Shield || CPUOption != ShotgunOption.Shield);
        } while (QUIT == false || gameCount == 3);
```

Heres my ShotgunOption enum method

```
enum ShotgunOption
     {
         Shoot = 1,
         Reload = 2,
         Shield = 3,


     }
```

Comment: Error message is self explanatory. Looks like `CPUOption` is also type of `ShotgunOption`.

Comment: The error message is quite explanatory, you can't compare ShotgunOption  to an int because they are different types. What is in your ShotgunOption  class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to use explicit conversion as ShotgunOption is an enum.

```
if((int)CPUOption == 1)
{ 
     ...
}
```

You have used below code to convert `int` to your `enum` type, so it should be clear that you need to adopt reverse process to compare enum type to an int

```
ShotgunOption CPUOption = (ShotgunOption)computer.Next(1, 3);
```

Comment: Just to clarify - you have to cast your enum type to an int to compare it to the corresponding `int` type.